# Uses of SUBSTRING in SQL Partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have created a table and partitioned it(the code is [here](http://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/), Please see the **Example of horizontal partitioning with creating a new partitioned table** part)
I have use the following **Partition function**:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitioningByMonth] (datetime)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('20140201', '20140301', '20140401',
               '20140501', '20140601', '20140701', '20140801', 
               '20140901', '20141001', '20141101', '20141201');
```

**And my SCHEMA is** :

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PartitionBymonth
AS PARTITION PartitioningBymonth
TO (January, February, March, 
    April, May, June, July, 
    Avgust, September, October, 
    November, December);
```

**And My table create Query is** :

```
CREATE TABLE Reports
(ReportDate datetime PRIMARY KEY,
MonthlyReport varchar(max))
ON PartitionBymonth (ReportDate);
GO
```

if i insert values which are **in the year of** `2014` (i mean `20140105`, `20140205`, ...... ), it works fine :

```
INSERT INTO Reports (ReportDate,MonthlyReport)
SELECT '20140105', 'ReportJanuary' UNION ALL
SELECT '20140205', 'ReportFebryary' UNION ALL
SELECT '20140308', 'ReportMarch' UNION ALL
```

But problem occurs when i insert any value of `2015`,`2016`,`2017`.....:

```
   INSERT INTO Reports (ReportDate,MonthlyReport)
    SELECT '20150105', 'ReportJanuary' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20150206', 'ReportFebryary' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20150309', 'ReportMarch' UNION ALL
```

as it push it only the last partition (`20141201` i mean `December` partition). But i want them to go  `January` , `February` , `March` partition.
I know my problem is in `PARTITION FUNCTION` because i wrote ('20140201', '20140301',......) only for 2014 year.
But i want to count the **Month only** .Is there any way so that it only see the month only   2015**03**01 rather than year or day.(can i use SUBSTRING in any part )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a computed column to your table as

```
ReportDateP as MONTH(ReportDate) PERSISTED
```

and create the table with partition on this computed column

Then create the partition function as follows

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [NewPartitioning] (int)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Comment: Good answer but is there any better way (without adding new column to main table) ?. Think about it, if you face complex situation , i mean word rather than number ...... can i use SUBSTRING

Comment: It does not seem to be possible using a value of a function like substring directly to partition function. So I could only produce computed column solution at first. Your requirement should be a common one but I could not see any answer for this on the web

Answer (score 0):

You can not use SubQuery in Partions system. Use Eralper Method for partitioning this portion

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PartitionBymonth
AS PARTITION PartitioningBymonth
TO (January, February, March, 
    April, May, June, July, 
    Avgust, September, October, 
    November, December);
```